# Memory leak in API create Contact

Tags: api

I am trying to use PHP on the Command Line to import 90,000 contacts to Civi 5.0. It seem like there is a memory like when calling:
civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', $usrArray);

Does anyone know what code in the api could be causing this?

The looping of the CSV has been written not to use up more memory than the line being read, this has been tested alone with memory_get_usage();

Best,
Joel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have been running this patch in production for some months to address the memory leak

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11615

When we first deployed it we hit a bug on the use of cloning the DAO in export. I removed that place however there is one remaining when exporting related contacts and I closed the PR until I had a chance to address that

```
      $allRelContactArray[$rel][$allRelContactDAO->refContact] = clone($allRelContactDAO);
```

I've now updated for that issue & re-submitted - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12276